# Prototype error in Magento

Tags: magento, prototypejs

I'm using the HelloResponsive EE theme on a Magento 1.13 EE deployment.

In setting up an extention for the eWAY gateway, I was told there was an error in the Prototype.js file that was interfering with the JSON post.

Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object prototype.js:126 addMethods prototype.js:126 create prototype.js:115 (anonymous function) wishlist.js:38

for (var i = 0, length = properties.length; i < length; i++) klass.addMethods(properties[i]);

The custom theme does use JQuery as well, so this may be a conflict issue. But when I try moving the JQuery call before the Prototype call, the JQuery functions stop working.

Can anyone help explain 1. whether or not the error is related to the Prototype / JQuery conflict (I am using a noConflict script) and 2. how best to fix this?

Thanks!

Randy

Comment: You are using PrototypeJS 1.7 - the latest version is 1.7.1 can you try out upgrading to see if that clears up the error http://prototypejs.org/download/

Comment: I am having the same issue, has anyone found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer in this thread and see if it can help you. Essentially, I had an outdated template file in my theme that was missing some key variable definitions:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7682/error-in-prototype-js